# Grammatischer Typ und Schreibweise von Adjektiven, die in bestimmten Bezügen stehen

Tags: grammar, capitalization, nominalization

Welchen grammatischen Typ haben in *Die Kategorien Gut und Böse* die beiden Wörter *gut* und *böse*, und schreibt man sie groß oder klein? Google findet beides.

Ich vermute, es handelt sich um Substantivierungen, und man schreibt sie groß. In *Die Kategorien Mensch und Tier* wäre das eindeutig. Da man aber sowohl sagen kann *Ich bin Mensch* als auch *Ich bin böse*, *Ich bin* also sowohl mit Substantiv als auch mit Adjektiv stehen kann, bin ich mir keineswegs sicher. Warum sollte eine Kategorie nicht quasi analog von einem Adjektiv bestimmt werden?

In *Jenseits von Gut und Böse* ist die Substantivierung viel naheliegender (in der Bedeutung *Jenseits des Guten und des Bösen*). Die einfache Analogie (*Die Kategorien "Das Gute und das Böse"*) passt aber nicht, weil *Das Gute* etwas anderes beschreibt als (so würde ich die *Kategorie "Gut"* mal umschreiben) *Alle Dinge, die gut sind, kommen in diese Kiste*.

Ich bitte auch um Korrektur des Titels dieser Frage - ich konnte ihn einfach nicht griffig formulieren.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Duden verweist in diesem Bezug auf Rechtschreibregel §72:

> Als Substantive gebrauchte Adjektive und Partizipien werden in der Regel großgeschrieben.

Daher ist deine Vermutung richtig.

Die Substantivierung bezieht sich hierbei auf `Die Kategorie` - Jede Kategorie wird durch einen Namen gekennzeichnet, der grundsätzlich ein Substantiv ist.

Comment: nur weil ich da grade drüber stolpere: wird `großgeschrieben` nicht `groß geschrieben` geschrieben? `groß` ist doch ein adverb das beschreibt wie ich etwas schreibe, oder?

Comment: @Alex: Laut dem Duden nicht: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/groszschreiben